# Use route component property for ngIf

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I am trying to use a property off the router to trigger an ngIf but am not sure of the correct syntax in the html. Angular2 RC6

```
{
  path: 'detail/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
},

<div *ngIf="router.component = HeroDetailComponent">
            some text to be shown if the HeroDetailComponent is loaded
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? it is not valid I guess.

Comment: I believe the "correct" way is to call functions. I.E. `*ngIf="EnableDulaView()"` and you would define the specifics of that function in your export class

Comment: is this `div` inside of `HeroDetailComponent's` template?

Answer (score -1):

use `===` not reflected on angular docs page....

Comment: [Did you just answer your own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @ndesign11 Your answer isn't clear to us. Could you make it little [clearer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659)?